# How to process a Float32Array in the shader? (WebGL)

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

As far as I know, it is possible to use `Uint8Array` as a texture in WebGL. But how is it possible to pass a large `Float32Array` or `Float64Array` to the shader efficiently? The float values are not in the (0.0, 1.0) range, and may be negative too.

I know, some devices does not support `high precision float`, and it is not a problem, if some precision is lost during the process.

Comment: [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to enable floating point textures with code like

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
  alert("sorry, no floating point textures");
  return;
}
```

Now you can create textures with `Float32Array` using

```
gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalformat, width, height, 0, 
              format, gl.FLOAT, someFloat32Array);
```

Note that being able to filter a floating point texture is a separate extension so if you need to filter you'll have to check for that too

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
if (!ext) {
  alert("sorry, can't filter floating point textures");
  return;
}
```

Otherwise you need to set texture filtering to `NEAREST`

Note: in WebGL2 you can read from floating point textures by default. but you use an internal type of `gl.RGBA32F`. Filtering is still optional so you need to try to enable `OES_texture_float_linear`.

To render to them (attach them to a framebuffer). In WebGL1 you need to check for `WEBGL_color_buffer_float`. In WebGL2 you need to check for `EXT_color_buffer_float`.